# GCP service account token expires

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I followed the tutorial https://github.com/jcbsmpsn/gke-rbac-walkthrough to grant a service account access to GKE and it worked but later the service account token expired and I had to renew it. Is there a way to make the token non expiry?

Comment: Potentially of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048945/oauth-v2-google-api-expiry-access-token

Answer (score 0):

When access token expires, [refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-10) can be used to obtain new access tokens. It is the Authorization Server that will issue a refresh token to the client which is then used to obtain a new access token. This is done at (d) as per this [Protocol Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-7), basically the refresh token is included with the access token when it is being issued.

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) provides more details regarding the process of refreshing an access token.